# How can Clojure data-structures best be tagged with a type?

Tags: data-structures, types, clojure

I'm writing a program that's manipulating polynomials. I'm defining polynomials recursively as either a term (base case) or a sum or product of polynomials (recursive cases).
Sums and products are completely identical as far as their contents are concerned. They just contain a sequence of polynomials. But they need to be processed very differently. So to distinguish them I have to somehow tag my sequences of polynomials.
Currently I have two records - Sum and Product - defined. But this is causing my code to be littered with the line `(:polynomials sum-or-product)` to extract the contents of polynomials. Also printing out even small polynomials in the REPL produces so much boilerplate that I have to run everything through a dedicated prettyprinting routine if I want to make sense of it.
Alternatives I have considered are tagging my sums and products using metadata instead, or putting a `+` or `*` symbol at the head of the sequence. But I'm not convinced that either of these approaches are good style and I'm wondering if there's perhaps another option I haven't considered yet.

Comment: Hmm, why do you have to extract the contents? What operations are occurring "outside" on them? Can you move them "inside" by defining a protocol that both types support?

Comment: For example I might try to multiply everything out. I. e. I'll turn `(a+b)(c+d)` into `(ac+ad+bc+bd)`. I'm not sure how helpful this is but you can take a look at the code here: https://github.com/SOberhoff/tnoc/blob/ip/src/tnoc/ip.clj

Comment: Thanks for the link, the book looks very interesting. Definitely see that the code is not getting leverage from the use of Sum and Product types. One way to do that is to create a protocol that both types, probably along with a Term type, implement. The protocol has at least 3 methods: Render()- produces a string; Value()- produces a calculation; and Constituents()- returns the members. Then redo the higher level operations in terms of those methods, adding other methods to the protocol as necessary to abstract over Sum, Product and Term types in a common way.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a `+` or `*` symbol at the head of the sequence sounds like it would print out nicely. I would try implementing the processing of these two different "types" via [multimethods](https://clojure.org/reference/multimethods), which keeps the calling convention neat and extensible. That document starts from object-oriented programmin view, but the "area of a shape" is a very neat example on what this approach can accomplish.

In your case you'd use `first` of the `seq` to determine if you are dealing with a sum or a product of polynomials, and the multimethod would automagically use the correct implementation.